# Word boundaries in Atlas Search regex operator

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I use the [regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/regex/) operator in my MongoDB Atlas search because the data is indexed using a [keyword analyzer](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/analyzers/keyword/), meaning that the whole string of a field is indexed as one single "word".

Because of this, exact word matches don't work like they would with the default analyzer. If the title of a document is `JavaScript beginner tutorial` then a search for `JavaScript` will not match. Instead, I use regex **wildcards** to find single words within this larger string. Which looks like this:

```
'(.*)' + 'JavaScript' + '(.*)'
```

This works. However, **I want to give exact word matches an extra boost** in the search score. Hence I want to run an **additional regex query that looks for either only whitespace before or after the word, or the word being at the beginning and/or end of the string**.

For example, when I search for `Java`, I want `Java beginner tutorial` to rank higher than `JavaScript beginner tutorial`. Currently, this is not the case, because the wildcards look for *any* characters.

The **normal Regex operators don't seem to work with the Atlas regex search**. I tried things like word boundaries `\bJava\b` or others, but none of them had an effect.

Comment: Try `(.*[^A-Za-z0-9_])?Java([^A-Za-z0-9_].*)?`. From what I see in the docs, the regex flavor is Lucene, and those patterns are all automatically anchored at start/end.

Comment: I used it like this: `regex: { query: '\b' + word + '\b' [...]}`

Comment: Please see the above comment. Also, maybe `regex: { query: '.*\b' + word + '\b.*' [...]}` will work, but if it is really Lucene, this won't help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your first solution seems to work! I have to try it out for a few more minutes to be really sure. The documentation says `The Atlas Search regex operator uses the 
Lucene regular expression engine
, which differs from 
Perl Compatible Regular Expressions
.`
Is this the reason why `\b` is not working? Do I understand your first solution correctly, it excludes results where a letter or digit appears before the word?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Just found your answer on another question with explains the Lucene behavior! Awesome!

Comment: Then let's close as a duplicate and keep as a flagpost.